# compilation error while connecting mysql from c++

Tags: c++, mysql

I am trying to run sample program for mysql c++ connect. each time getting error. Here are various way I tried from various solutions with no luck.

Any help will be highly appreciated!

```
g++ -o a temp.cpp -lmysqlcppconn  // error : many error like /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../../lib/libmysqlcppconn.so: undefined reference to `mysql_next_result@libmysqlclient_18'


 g++ -o test -Iinclude -Llib -L/usr/lib64/mysql -lmysqlclient temp.cpp // error: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmysqlclient


    g++ -Wall -o firsttry_prog -I/usr/include/mysqlcppconn -L/usr/lib/mysqlcppconn temp.cpp -lmysqlcppconn  // ERRor : kind of dozens error : /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../../lib/libmysqlcppconn.so: undefined reference to `mysql_stmt_field_count@libmysqlclient_18'


    sudo g++ -Wall -I/usr/include/cppconn -o testapp temp.cpp -L/usr/lib -lmysqlcppconn  //gives dozens of error
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you don't have the mysqlclient lib installed.

Try this if you made sure you installed it:

```
g++ -o temp.o -c `mysql_config --cflags` temp.cpp
g++ -o temp temp.o -lmysqlcppconn `mysql_config --libs`
```

see [MySQL - Building C API Client Programs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/c-api-building-clients.html)

Comment: I installed it again `sudo apt-get install mysql-client` but no change!

Comment: Simple running it like : `g++ -o a temp.cpp -lmysqlcppconn` should not work?

Comment: how to find default installation location for mysql? m

Comment: Thanks, some progress! First line executes successfully. 2nd line gives again `temp.o: In function `main':
/home/technoworld/Desktop/temp.cpp:23: undefined reference to `get_driver_instance'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
` error!

Comment: Then it gives `/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../../lib/libmysqlcppconn.so: undefined reference to `mysql_stmt_store_result@libmysqlclient_18'
` like many errors

Comment: Try with `g++ -o temp temp.o -lmysqlcppconn `mysql_config --libs`

Comment: thanks a lot. but still `/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../../lib/libmysqlcppconn.so: undefined reference to `mysql_next_result@libmysqlclient_18'
`

Comment: as per the manual `If you get undefined reference errors for the uncompress or compress function, add -lz to the end of your link command and try again.` so I gave `g++ -o temp temp.o -lmysqlcppconn mysql_config --libs -lz` even no luck!